# how can I count all row and count group by on one tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i write a SQL Code like this

```
    SELECT count(tn.[ProductName])  as ProductCount,tn.[CategoryID],tp.estbProducerID,tp.NewProducer
from [tpdcn] tp,[tpdtn] tn
left join [tpdcn]
on tn.parentid = tpdcn.libDocumentID
where tp.libdocumentID = @id
group by tn.[CategoryID],tp.estbProducerID
```

it's show

```
   Product Count    CategoryID     estbProducerID
        2               1            810600017   
        9               2            810600017  
        2               3            810600017  
        2               4            810600017  
        1               5            810600017
```

but I need more one field to show like this

```
 Product Count  CategoryID     estbProducerID     Product Count All   
        2               1            810600017                16
        9               2            810600017  
        2               3            810600017  
        2               4            810600017  
        1               5            810600017
```

What should I do to make it in one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

```
count(*) over() as [Product Count All]
```

It will count the rows using the specified partition. Without a partition clause it count all rows.

```
select count(T.[ProductName]) as ProductCount,
       T.CategoryID,
       T.estbProducerID,
       T.NewProducer,
       T.[Product Count All]
from (
     select tn.[ProductName],
            tn.[CategoryID],
            tp.estbProducerID,
            tp.NewProducer,
            count(*) over() as [Product Count All]
     from [tpdcn] tp,[tpdtn] tn
       left join [tpdcn]
         on tn.parentid = tpdcn.libDocumentID
     where tp.libdocumentID = @id
     ) as T
group by T.[CategoryID],
         T.estbProducerID
```

Comment: :') Thanks for your help but it's not work with my situation, or I can't adapt it not sure :'(

Comment: i use count(tn.[ProductName]) over() as [Product Count All] like this and It's show a error 
Column 'tpdtn.ProductName' is invalid in the select list

Then I put tpdtn.ProductName in Group by but It's show the Product Count all as "16" it's true but it sorting Product count by category as "1" it's count per pieces :'(

Comment: @TouchyVivace Ok, that is not what I answered. You should use `count(*) over()`.

Comment: it's work but show value in product count all as "5"

Comment: @TouchyVivace Ahh, ok, I added a reworked query that should do what you want.

Comment: BTW, your from/join clause looks a bit suspicious. `from [tpdcn] tp,[tpdtn] tn
left join [tpdcn]`. You are referencing the same table twice and once in a cartesian product. Not sure what that will do to your query.

Comment: oh my god dude it's working !!!!!!!! Thank you very much for your help but i'm so new in Database

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT count(tn.[ProductName])  as ProductCount,tn.[CategoryID],tp.estbProducerID,tp.NewProducer,
from [tpdcn] tp,[tpdtn] tn
left join [tpdcn]
on tn.parentid = tpdcn.libDocumentID
where tp.libdocumentID = @id
group by tn.[CategoryID],tp.estbProducerID
)

select *,sum(ProductCount) as  Product Count All  from cte group by tn.[CategoryID],tp.estbProducerID
```